# grunt build or bower adds a useless dependency for highstocks

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm using yeoman, grunt and bower and highstock library.
When I build my app (grunt build) this generate these 3 lines

```
<script src="bower_components/highstock/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highstock/js/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highstock/js/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>
```

BUT, as highstock includes high charts this line should not be there and this makes errors

```
<script src="bower_components/highstock/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
```

the error is http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16

How to remove this line in the build ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is [`grunt-bower-install`](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install) at work. `gbi` is a task that looks through the dependencies in your project's `bower.json`, and injects their appropriate references into your HTML. In order for it to work, each Bower package needs to specify a `main` property in *its* `bower.json` file.

So, the [`bower.json` file for `highcharts`](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/bower.json) looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "highcharts",
  "version": "v3.0.10-modified",
  "main": [
    "js/highcharts.src.js",
    "js/highcharts-more.src.js",
    "js/modules/exporting.src.js"
  ],  
  "ignore": [
    "errors",
    "exporting-server",
    "gfx",
    "lib",
    "samples",
    "studies",
    "test",
    "tools",
    "utils",
    "ant",
    "build.md",
    "build.properties",
    "build.xml"
  ]
}
```

Because it lists 3 different files, `gbi` is interpreting that as "you need these three files to make this Bower package work." I have no familiarity with `highcharts`, but if you know that to be false-- in other words, you only need one of those files for it to work-- then it would be helpful to you and others to send a pull request correcting their `bower.json` file.

As far as a fix for now, you can specify an `overrides` property in your project's `bower.json`, that lists only the file you need, such as:

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "highcharts": "~3.0.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "highcharts": {
      "main": "js/highcharts.src.js"
    }
  }
}
```

The next time you run `grunt bowerInstall`, it will sort itself out.

Note: Make sure you're using the latest `grunt-bower-install` to use the new `overrides` feature.

Comment: when I run grunt bowerInstall I have an error : "task not found". When I run grunt serve there is still the same output. I have tried to remove the files in highstock bower.json fil but they still appear when running grunt serve. How is this possible ?